# Using VBA To Compare Cells From Different Sheets And Insert New Row On One Sheet When Cells Don't Match

Tags: excel, vba

I have two worksheets in which I need to compare the entity id in worksheet Blah with the entity id in worksheet Blah1. The entity ids are stored in column A on both sheets. If an entity id exists in Blah but not Blah 1, I need to insert a blank row on the Blah 1 table where it's missing the entity id. The range of rows I need to compare will change from month to month. I know that rows 5 through 92 on Blah 2 match rows 2 through 89, but it starts inserting at row 11 and continues to insert rows until I hit escape. I know I also probably need another if that tells the code to go to the next I if the entity id is blank, but I'm not sure how to do that.

So in summary, I need to compare the entity ids and insert a new row for any entity ids that are missing. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
 Sub InsertNewRow()
 Dim i As Long, j As Long, lastrow1 As Long, lastrow2 As Long

 lastrow1 = Sheets("Blah").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
 lastrow2 = Sheets("Blah1").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

     For j = 2 To lastrow2
      For i = 5 To lastrow1
        If Sheets("Blah").Cells(j, 1) <> Sheets("Blah1").Cells(i, 1) Then
            Sheets("Blah1").Cells(i, 1).EntireRow.Insert
 End If
     Next i
 Next j
 End Sub
```

Comment: Should they match row by row? or only exist in the other?

Comment: Whatever entity id is in worksheet Blah must also be in worksheet Blah1. After inserting rows on Blah1 I was going to fill in the blank rows with the appropriate information from Blah.

Comment: But no, the entity ids do not have to line up exactly from one sheet to the other

Comment: Then it does not matter where you add the lines.  Just cycle through the first sheet and see if it exists in the second, if not then copy and paste the line to the bottom of the second list.

Comment: And how would I do that?

Comment: There are many many examples on how to do that on this site alone a quick search: `copy row to another page based on criteria vba`,`Find if value exists in another sheet vba`, and `Find last row with value vba` will give a lot of examples.

Answer (score 0):

I was actually able to find my answer on Mr. Excel. I think it was the double Fors that was messing me up. Once that was figured out, I was able to figure out how to add in the values I needed from sheet Blah to sheet Blah1. In searching based on what Scott said, I wasn't able to find what I actually needed. I'm sure there's an easier way to do this, and as I get more experience maybe I'll figure it out.

```
    Sub InsertRows()
     Dim lastrow As Long, i As Long, j As Long

     lastrow = Sheets("Blah").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    j = 14

    For i = 2 To lastrow
    If Sheets("Blah1").Cells(j, 1).Value <> Sheets("Blah").Cells(i, 1).Value Then
     Sheets("Blah1").Rows(j).Insert Shift:=xlDown
    Sheets("Blah1").Cells(j, 2).Value = Sheets("Blah").Cells(i, 10).Value
    Sheets("Blah1").Cells(j, 3).Value = Sheets("Blah").Cells(i, 11).Value
    Sheets("Blah1").Cells(j, 5).Value = "2017"
    Sheets("Blah1").Cells(j, 6).Value = Sheets("Blah").Cells(i, 2).Value
    Sheets("Blah1").Cells(j, 7).Value = Sheets("Blah").Cells(i, 3).Value
    Sheets("Blah1").Cells(j, 8).Value = Sheets("Blah").Cells(i, 4).Value
     Sheets("Blah1").Cells(j, 9).Value = Sheets("Blah").Cells(i, 5).Value

    End If
     j = j + 1
    Next i
    End Sub
```